# activity monitor display in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cpu-usage

I once connected an iphone running a specific app to a Mac running Xcode 9.x and could see in the left hand pane a horizontal bar graph of CPU performance, memory usage and maybe a graph on memory leak

I was never able to reproduce this display.

Would appreciate any pointer on how I can reproduce this view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try *View* > *Navigators* > *Debug Navigator* in Xcode.

**Edit**

You need to be running the app for the horizontal bar, memory usage, etc. to show up.

[image]

Comment: You should edit that comment into your answer -- it'd be a big improvement. Add a screen grab for extra credit... people vote up when you include pictures.

Comment: Thx @Caleb . Will do.